# force catch on try error response in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

the api i am using returns an error that is 200 status:

```
function searchCharacters(text: string, page: number) {
  return axios
    .get('http://www.omdbapi.com/', {
      params: {
        apiKey,
        s: text,
        page,
      },
    })
    .then(({data}) => {
      if (data.Error) {
        return data.Error;
      }
      return data.Search;
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.error(e);
      return [];
    });
}
```

i want data.Error passed on catch e value? but the problem in react native is it crash, i want to show the error message text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no proof of that but I don't think raising or throwing an exception inside a success callback is recommended. I would suggest to return promises instead and handling callbacks outside your `searchCharacters()` function using async/await

```
async function searchCharacters(text: string, page: number) {
  return axios
    .get('http://www.omdbapi.com/', {
      params: {
        apiKey,
        s: text,
        page,
      },
    })
    .then(({data}) => {
      if (data.Error) {
        return Promise.reject(data.Error);
      }
      return Promise.resolve(data.Search);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      return Promise.reject(e)
    });
}


// you could call your `searchCharacters()` like this

const Search = await searchCharacters('hello', 2).catch(error =>{
    console.log('an error has occurred', error);
    // maybe set your list to an empty list here
})

if(Search) {
   console.log('success', Search);
   // maybe set your list to the search result here
}
```